# VF2 algorithm - implementation

Tags: algorithm, graph, subgraph, isomorphism

I have a problem with the VF2 algorithm implementation. Everything seems to be working perfectly in many cases, however there is a problem I cannot solve.

The algorithm does not work on the example below. In this example, we are comparing two identical graphs (see image below). Starting vertex is 0.
The set P, that is calculated inside s0, stores the powerset of all pairs of vertices.

[image: graph]

Below is a pseudocode included in the publications about VF2 on which I based my implementation.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=B51AD0DAEDF60D6C8AB589A39A570257?doi=10.1.1.101.5342&rep=rep1&type=pdf

http://www.icst.pku.edu.cn/intro/leizou/teaching/2012-autumn/papers/part2/VF2%20A%20%28sub%29Graph%20Isomorphism%20Algorithm%20For%20Matching%20Large%20Graphs.pdf

Comments on the right side of /* describe the way I understand the code:

I'm not sure if creating the P() set is valid as described below. Powersets of pairs are iterated in lexicographical order by first and then second value of pair.

```
PROCEDURE Match(s)
  INPUT: an intermediate state s; the initial state s0 has M(s0)=empty
  OUTPUT: the mappings between the two graphs
  IF M(s) covers all the nodes of G2 THEN
    OUTPUT M(s)
  ELSE
    Compute the set P(s) of the pairs candidate for inclusion in M(s)
    /*by powerset of all succesors from already matched M(s) if not empty or
    /*predestors to already matched M(s) if not empty
    /*or all possible not included vertices in M(s)
    FOREACH (n, m)∈ P(s)
      IF F(s, n, m) THEN
    Compute the state s ́ obtained by adding (n, m) to M(s)
    /*add n to M1(s), exclude from T1(s)
    /*add m to M2(s), exclude from T2(s)
    /*M1(s) is now M1(s'), other structures belong to s' too
    CALL Match(s′)
      END IF
    END FOREACH
    Restore data structures
    /*Return all structures as from before foreach
  END IF
END PROCEDURE
```

When the algorithm goes to s4, when returing from the function, it looses information about good vertices match.
It results in searching the subgraph-isomorphism  ({(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(5,3),(6,4)}) - even though the graphs are isomorphic.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It's more than half a year already. Have you found the answer for your own question yet? Or just let it be and move on?

Answer (score 2):

I think that to know your question "what am I doing wrong here", it is necessary to include some of your code here. You re-implemented the code yourself, based on the pseudo-code presented in the paper? or you were doing the matching with the help of some graph-processing packages?

For me I didn't have time to dig in the details, but I work with graphs as well, so I tried with networkx (a Python package) and Boost 1.55.0 library (very extensive C++ lib for graph). Your example and another example of a graph with 1000 nodes, 1500 edges return the correct matching (the trivial case of matching a graph with itself).

```
import networkx as nx
G1 = nx.Graph()
G2 = nx.Graph()

G1.clear()
G2.clear()

G1.add_nodes_from(range(0,7))
G2.add_nodes_from(range(0,7))
G1.add_edges_from([(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,5), (5,6)])
G2.add_edges_from([(0,1), (1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (2,5), (5,6)])

from networkx.algorithms import isomorphism
GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G2,G1)
print GM.is_isomorphic()
GM.mapping
```

True

Out[39]:
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6}